# Why is Python Pandas loc not returning a single item?

Tags: python, pandas

For an assignment I need to access entries in a CSV file by the column name and index.

I am using a for loop to get each index. Contrary to my expectations,

```
read.loc[[i], ["magType"]]
```

returns something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unxiq.png)

instead of just "mb" which is what I would expect based on a pandas cheatsheet (linked below)
Why is this? And how can I get just the item (in this case "mb" without the magType and 0)?

```
import pandas as pd
read = pd.read_csv("earthquake_data.csv")
print(read.loc[[0], ["magType"]])
```

> magType
>
> > 0 mb

https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/PandasPythonForDataScience.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.loc[0, "magType"]` returns the element at `0`-th row and `magType` column - presumably the result you desire.

`read.loc[[0], ["magType"]]`, on the other hand, returns a *slice* of the DataFrame, with columns from `["magType"]`, with all the rows whose indices are in `[0]`. (Compare `read.loc[[1, 2, 3], ["magType", "magnitude"]]` or `read.loc[[0:10], ["magType", "magnitude"]]` to see a general case of this.) Like any other DataFrame, it has indices and column names.

Comment: I'd also throw in that the canonical way to access a *scalar* by row/column labels is `at`, i.e. `read.at[0, 'magType']`. Be careful with the description "the `0`th row", alignment between integer position and label is only true when your index is a regular `pd.RangeIndex`.